# Google Spreadsheet, partial formatting using formula in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheet to make some calculations.

At the bottom of my table I need SUM, AVG and some others and everything is fine.

But I made a long cell with all the text, like this:

```
="Hi at all, this is my report: "&SUM(B:B)&" are the sum of my fingers, "&AVG(C:C)&" is the avg of my sons."
```

and so on.

Everything works. But I need to bold the `SUM(B:B)`.

I won't use single cells for math results.

I tried with ....**"&SUM(B:B)&"**.... but obviously I get  in my cell and not the bold font weight.

How to style from formula in cell?

Comment: this cant be done

Answer (score 6):

Partial formatting of cell content is a recent addition to Google Sheets, and it not really integrated with the rest of spreadsheet logic. The only thing you can format in this way is a string entered directly into a cell, as `some text here`. Using any kind of formula, even the simplest `="some text here"`, is incompatible with partial formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Also pointing out you can not currently carry over formatting using an equation.  In the original post for example, if the cell C1 had held the value =sum(B:B), and then been bolded, that bold would NOT carry over into a new cell C2 that contained 
="Trying to keep the bold sum here"&C1

Answer (score -1):

In the cell you want to be in bold, just go to:
`Format-->Conditional Formatting-->B` (for bold).
I also chose in: `Format Cell` If... --->`if cell is not Empty`.
From now on, that cell will be bold every time there´s a result (not empty cell).

Comment: In that case, you could just make the cell bold at all times, because you can't see it being bold when its empty anyway, and formatting has no effect on formulas either.